# Select latest available value SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce, cumulative-sum

Below is a test table for simplification of what I am looking to achieve in a query. I am attempting to create a query using a running sum which inserts into `column b` that last sum result that was not null. If you can imagine, i'm looking to have a cumulative sum the purchases of a customer every day, some days no purchases occurs for a particular customer thus I want to display the latest sum for that particular customer instead of 0/null.

```
CREATE TABLE test (a int, b int);
insert into test values (1,null);
insert into test values (2,1);
insert into test values (3,3);
insert into test values (4,null);
insert into test values (5,5);
insert into test values (6,null);

1- select sum(coalesce(b,0)),coalesce(0,sum(b)) from test
2- select a, sum(coalesce(b,0)) from test group by a order by a asc
3- select a, sum(b) over (order by a asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) from test group by a,b order by a asc
```

I'm not sure if my interpretation of how coalesce works is correct. I thought this `sum(coalesce(b,0))` will insert 0 where b is null and always take the latest cumulative sum of column b.

Think I may have solved it with query 3.

The result I expect will look like this:

```
a  | sum
--------
1   
2    1
3    4
4    4
5    9
6    9
```

Each records of a displays the last cumulative sum of column b.

Any direction would be of valuable.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide expected output

Comment: Your second query only takes account records with `a` being `4` - and your sample data only contains one of these

Comment: Your question would benefit from an illustration of your expected results. In  the example you have provided, what do you expect the output of this query to be?

Comment: I don't see why the second query should return 6 based on your description? Customer "4" had no purchases in the sample data.

Comment: @Dutow I guess(!) that OP appears wants to compute cumulative sums over `b` restarting at each `null`, with the ordering given by `a`. Again, it's only guesswork ...

Comment: coalesce(0,sum(b)) will always be 0, thats how coalesce works, take the first not null

Comment: @collapsar - no, i don't want to restart at each `null` value but to replicate the last cumulative sum in the following row if `column b` is empty/null value such as for the re-written example above.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres you can also use the window function of SUM for a cummulative sum.

Example:

> ```
> create table test (a int, b int);
> insert into test (a,b) values (1,null),(2,1),(3,3),(4,null),(5,5),(6,null);
> ```

> ```
> select a, sum(b) over (order by a, b) as "sum"
> from test;
> ```
>
> ```
>  a |  sum
> -- | ----
>  1 | null
>  2 |    1
>  3 |    4
>  4 |    4
>  5 |    9
>  6 |    9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4e631909d1446bf13b01ad374a19aa9b)*

And if "a" isn't unique, but you want to group on a?
Then you could use a suminception:

```
select a, sum(sum(b)) over (order by a) as "sum"
from test
group by a
```

Comment: seems more simple than what I proposed for query 3.

Comment: @OAK sometimes extra things for a function are already an implicit default. But you can always set them explicit.

Comment: @LukStors - I had a typo in the results table (fixed now). Your solution seems to work and query 3 as well albeit is more convoluted.

Comment: @OAK I noticed that you had added a group by in that 3th one.  So I've included a suminception into the answer. (it's not a real word, probably)

Comment: I kinda also added that 2nd query just to showcase that the window functions are processed after the GROUP BY clause.  While most would expect the opposite.