# SQL - How Cumulative Sum when group by values are missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

As a follow-up to my previous ticket - which I now believe the example was too simple ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423133/select-latest-available-value-sql/51423540?noredirect=1#comment89821434_51423540)), I prepared an example of a scenario where I'm looking to aggregate column `cus_sum` group on the `date_col` column and the `cus` column representing the unique customer number. 
I wish to generate a series of dates for instance (function `generate series`) from the 1st of January 2018 till the 10th of January 2018 and then have a cumulative sum of column `cus_sum` for each customer. As in the case below, you can imagine that there are days without information at all and days where not all customers have any records - regardless i want to show their cumulative sum throughout that period.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (date_col date, cus int, cus_sum int);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-01', 1, 5);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-02', 1, 12);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-02', 2, 14);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-03', 2, 8);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-03', 2, 10);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-04', 1, 22);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-06', 2, 20);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-06', 1, 5);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-07', 1, 45);
    insert into test2 values ('2018-01-08', 2, 32);
```

The output should look like:

```
date_col       cus  cum_sum
"2018-01-01"    1   5
"2018-01-01"    2   0
"2018-01-02"    1   17
"2018-01-02"    2   14
"2018-01-03"    1   17
"2018-01-03"    2   32
"2018-01-04"    1   39
"2018-01-04"    2   32
"2018-01-05"    1   39
"2018-01-05"    2   32
"2018-01-06"    1   89
"2018-01-06"    2   52
"2018-01-07"    1   134
"2018-01-07"    2   52
"2018-01-08"    1   134
"2018-01-08"    1   84
```

Perhaps I should add that - one table I assume will be a virtual table that generates a list of dates in a given timeframe. The second table is a list of customers[1,3,4,5..10], products purchases (product volume) - which is what I wish to cumulative sum for every customer and everyday of the series.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have separate table for customers, so you can use CTE to generate the data range and then join croos join customer table to have all combinations of customer and dates, then you get the sum  from test2 table. the query will look like below -

```
WITH DateRange AS (
        SELECT
         [MyDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/01/2018')
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT
         [MyDate] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
        FROM
         DateRange
        WHERE
         [MyDate] <= '01/10/2018'
) SELECT
 d.[MyDate]
 c.cus
 (
  select isnull(sum(cus_sume),0) 
  from test2 t 
  where t.date = d.mydate 
  and c.cust = t.cust
 ) as cus_sum
FROM
 DateRange d 
 cross join customer c
order by d.MyDate
```

Comment: is it possible to adapt it to PostgreSQL?

Comment: it should work, did you get any exception?  I am not much familiar with PostageSQL, but this is generic SQL query which should work.

Answer (score 1):

The cross join of `generate_series()` and `unnest()` creates a virtual table of all possible values:

```
select distinct
    date_col::date, 
    cus, 
    coalesce(sum(cus_sum) over (partition by cus order by date_col), 0) as cum_sum
from generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-01-08', '1d') as date_col
cross join (select distinct cus from test2) c
left join test2 using (date_col, cus)   
order by date_col, cus

  date_col  | cus | cum_sum 
------------+-----+---------
 2018-01-01 |   1 |       5
 2018-01-01 |   2 |       0
 2018-01-02 |   1 |      17
 2018-01-02 |   2 |      14
 2018-01-03 |   1 |      17
 2018-01-03 |   2 |      32
 2018-01-04 |   1 |      39
 2018-01-04 |   2 |      32
 2018-01-05 |   1 |      39
 2018-01-05 |   2 |      32
 2018-01-06 |   1 |      44
 2018-01-06 |   2 |      52
 2018-01-07 |   1 |      89
 2018-01-07 |   2 |      52
 2018-01-08 |   1 |      89
 2018-01-08 |   2 |      84
(16 rows)
```

It looks like there are mistakes in the OP's expected results.

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a45691ee1d8ed5129090f498c401b6cc)

Comment: adapted the query above to my tables but the output isn't as expected. The `generate series` function is not creating the day time-frame as expected and defined - so missing days. The other issue i'm investigating is how to extrapolate all customers not only the ones defined in the array - it won't be effective to list all customers.

Comment: Ad 1. Surely `generate_series()` does what is shown in the answer. If you have problems with it show them in [DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10) Ad 2. You can `select distinct cus from test2` instead of `unnest(array[1,2])` - see the upddated answer.

Comment: got it to work - took more investigation as to how that query comes to life. Thanks a lot

Comment: a related question though - from an optimisation stand-point would it make sense to generate a series from the minimum found date in the database till today and in parallel find the first purchase date per customers - and start the cumulative sum from there on per customer. Or conversely generate one series from the first purchase of all customers moving forward.

Comment: The first option can lead to an overly complex query. I would bet on simplicity, that is, to generate a common series for all customers and possibly (optionally) delete the initial rows for each customer to the first non-zero value. The difference in performance between the two variants should not be great.